# Limit as $x$ approaches $0$ of $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{\cos x+e^x-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits

using l'hopitals $\ln(1+x)$ becomes $1/(1+x)$. How does the bottom derive? Can I just take it term by term?

Comment: Yes you can use the fact that the derivative of sum of functions is equal to sum of their derivatives.

Comment: Please use LaTeX markup to make your question more readable. Also, thanks for giving a little info about what you've tried! We appreciate that.

Comment: @ScottS.: Why do you need L'Hopital's Rule here as the limit reduces to $\dfrac{\ln 1}{-1 + 1 + 1} = \dfrac{0}{1} = 0$?

Comment: @Moo Good point, totally missed that :)

Comment: @KSplitX Please be careful with the updates, you have replaced the $\ln$ with $ln$ and $\cos$ with $cos$ in the title...

Comment: It still gets the message across, I simply made it into a fraction

Answer (score 3):

One cannot apply l'Hopital's rule to this question, as the limit is not an indeterminate form. The limit of the numerator is $0$ (as $\ln (1+x)$ is continuous and $\ln (1) = 0$). The limit of the denominator is $1$ (as $\cos x + e^x - 1$ is continuous, and at $0$ it is $1 + 1 - 1 = 1$).

So overall, your limit works out to be $\frac{0}{1} = 0$.